# Facebook like box showing duplicate profiles

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I am trying to use this [like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box) box on a site and getting duplicate profile pictures.

the code i have is something like this

```
<div class="box-facebook">
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%23%21%2Fpages%somePage%464535333&amp;width=282&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;connections=8&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=587" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is this a problem on my end or facebook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think (not 100%) that if you're logged in, then FB generates exactly the amount of images that are set in connections=8 parameter and fills it with your friends that like this page. If there are less than some are duplicated, if you log out of FB, this should disappear. I guess the only thing that can be done about it is submitting it to FB, or getting more friend to like your page ;)

Answer (score 2):

Facebook assigned this as a bug according to this thread on the Facebook Developers site: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285038208205121?browse=search_4f100b16473341577332946